# Xamarin.android - Pass data to my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have a List with my services, and on item selected i'm passing service type to my activity ServiceDetail like this:

**ServiceActivity**

```
void item_selected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    MenuContentItem selectedItem = (MenuContentItem)item[e.Position];
    if(selectedItem.Title == "COLLO") {
        var activity_go = new Intent(this, typeof(ServiceDetailActivity));
        activity_go.PutExtra("service_type", "Collo");
        StartActivity(activity_go);
    }
    if (selectedItem.Title == "SPALLA") {
        var activity_go = new Intent(this, typeof(ServiceDetailActivity));
        activity_go.PutExtra("service_type", "Spalla");
        StartActivity(activity_go);
    }
}
```

**ServiceDetailActivity**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ServiceDetail);
    //enable navigation mode to support tab layout
    this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
    AddTab("Introduzione", Resource.Mipmap.Icon, new IntroduzioneFragment());
    //intent data 
    string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("service_type") ?? "Data not available";
    IntroduzioneFragment fragment = new IntroduzioneFragment();
    // set data to pass to my fragment
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.PutString("text", text);
    fragment.Arguments = bundle;
}
// MY FRAGMENT - I would like "CUSTOM" my fragment "IntroduzioneFragment" like this:
class IntroduzioneFragment : Fragment {
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Tab, container, false);
        var sampleTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image_view);
        imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.slide1);
        // Get type of service
        var test = Arguments.GetString("text");
        if (test == "Collo") {
            sampleTextView.Text = "is collooooo";
        } else {
            sampleTextView.Text = "is not collo";
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

I don't want create one activity for each service, i would like just have one "Service activity detail" and custom text and image by service type.

**ERROR:** when I select item service:

```
System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on: 
var test = Arguments.GetString("text");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways of doing that.

If that is the activity that holds the fragment, you can call

```
this.Activity
```

inside fragment and just call any method of the activity after casting

```
AwesomceActivty castetActivity = (AwesomeActivity)this.Activity;
castetActivity.AwesomeMethod(12);
```

Or you can do that by using Delegates:

Define delegates in your Fragment class

```
namespace Awesome.Android {
     public class AwesomeFragment : Fragment {

       public delegate void OnAwesomePress (int number);
       public event OnAwesomePress sendOnAwesomePressEvent;
     }
}
```

You can assign it when you create a Framgent

```
AwesomeFragment fragment = new AwesomeFragment ();
fragment.OnAwesomePress += OnAwesomePress;
```

After that, you implement `OnAwesomePress` in your activity

```
private void OnAwesomePress (int number) {

}
```

Now, when you call `sendOnAwesomePressEvent` in your Fragment, that event will be passed to Activity.

```
sendOnAwesomePressEvent (10);
```

Comment: i used var test = this.Activity.Intent.GetStringExtra ("service_type") ?? "data not available"; on my framment, thank you!